# Access query to know which subforms have or have not been completed

Tags: mysql, ms-access, subform

I am developing a database to track assembly process of a product for use on a production floor, very similar to a router.  There is a main form (frm_WO) with 33 subforms.  Each subform represents a single step in the process, and is linked back to a field WONum from the parent table, tbl_WO. The subforms are listed on the main form in order of production but are not linked to each other in any way.  Technicians click a 'pass/fail' checkbox to indicate the step was completed. I would like to write a query that will tell me where each product is in the production process.  For example, if widget X has data for frm_Process 1 (and nothing else), widget Y has data for frm_Process1 and frm_Process2 (and nothing else) and widget Z has data for frm_Process 1, frm Process2, and frm_Process 3 (etc), I want to be able to quickly query and have it spit out data that looks like this:

Widget X Process 1
Widget Y Process 2
Widget Z Process 3

Is this possible since the subforms aren't linked?  Is the best solution to make a query where there is a field for the pass/fail status of each subform?

I'm very, very new to access so please make any response as simple as possible.

Thank you!

Comment: In order to answer your questions we need more information. How exactly are the subforms linked to the parent form? What attributes (columns) does tbl_WO have?

Comment: tbl_WO has WO Number, Part Number, Quanitity, Start Date, End Date.  The subforms generally contain WO Number (linked to WO Number from tbl_WO via a combo box linkage), 'Pass/Fail' and completion date.  There is no linkage between the subforms, only the one to many relationship of tbl_WO to each individual subform (aka a process step).  Does that help?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you add a table and put them in a relationship as shown below:

[image]

The benefit: Now you can query which widget has finished how many processes.

```
SELECT wo.WO_Number AS Widget, pr.process_ID AS Process
FROM tbl_WO AS wo INNER JOIN tbl_WO_processes AS pr ON wo.WO_number = pr_WO
WHERE WO_Number = [the widget your are looking for]
```

Now you need to make sure every subform writes its process_ID automatically in the table.

This will give you a table like:

```
Widget | Process
X      | 1
Y      | 4
Z      | 9
```

With some VBA code you could bring it into the form you want.

Would this be acceptable too? Do some widgets skip a process occasionally? If yes my solutions does not work properly. Then you would need a many to many relationship.

Keep us updated how you plan to proceed.